# shouldRasterize on CALayer breaks iOS 7 UINavigationBar background blur

Tags: ios, ios7, uikit, calayer

I'm doing some 3D transforms on a UINavigationController. In an attempt to increase performance and create prettier rendering (antialiased edges and content), I'm trying out `-[CALayer shouldRasterize]`. When enabling this on the view that UINavigationBar is contained in, the blur is removed, resulting in a broken look.

Is this simply a limitation of the underlying `_UIBackdropView` or does anyone know a way to work around this?

With `myNavigationController.view.layer.shouldRasterize = NO`:

[image: Normal]

With `myNavigationController.view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES`:

[image: Rasterized]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't found a way to properly handle this with `-[CALayer shouldRasterize]`. I did, however, succeed in creating a cached version of the view using the new iOS 7 method `-[UIView snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:]`